# looking for an html editor

Tags: php, html, editor

Hi I am looking for a simple html editor (not anything like wysiwyg), a simple html editor that would allow bold, italic and code like this [code][/code] [b][/b] etc..
Like the one in some vbulletin forums, Do you know where I can get one?

Comment: I'm using a WYSIWYG editor (CKEditor), but I don't know of any without WYSIWYG. You could just disable the WYSIWYG part and decrease the script file size with other packaging configurations. -- http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7315/_samples/bbcode.html

Comment: That is not a HTML editor, but a BB code parser.

Comment: Not programming. Google is your friend.

Comment: The best place where you can get it is Google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't understand if you want an editor for your local developing (Like Notepad++ suggested by Shomz) or a web editor to embed in your pages...

In the latter case, try [**MarkItUp**](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)! wich has a native option to use BBCode and its jQuery powered. See [*example here*](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/bbcode/) for the BBCode feature.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a good place to start.